# Azure wildcard subdomains

Tags: azure, subdomain

I have a reserved azure website and I've been following this article - http://www.stratospher.es/blog/post/wildcard-subdomains-in-windows-azure

I have added a wildcard cname record which points to mysite.azurewebsites.net

via the azure management portal --> manage domains. I have the added an entry into the domain names list:

test1.mysite.com

If i browse to this url it works perfectly. However, if then try test2.mysite.com I get a 404. If i was to add test2.mysite.com to the domain names list in azure then test2.mysite.com would then work.

What have I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply from the author of the article above. Basically when he wrote that Azure websites didnt exist, he was using the azure cloud app.

In Cloud apps if you want to use your own domain you just point it to whatever.cloudapp.net. Your not required to verifiy a 'custom' domain like you have to in azure websites.